# How to put default minimal nginx config of Symfony 4.3 in sub location?

Tags: symfony, nginx

How to put this is nginx config of Symfony 4.3 
https://symfony.com/doc/4.3/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx to sub location?

Config:

```
server {
    server_name domain.tld www.domain.tld;
    root /var/www/project/public;

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    internal;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
}

error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

Need put to location:

```
location /api {
               }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am find two variants with root or alias.

With root:

```
server {
server_name domain.tld www.domain.tld;
root /var/www/project/public;

    location /api {
        index index.php;
        root /var/www/project/api/public;
        try_files $uri /api/index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ ^/api(/index\.php(/|$)) {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME     index.php;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI    index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$1;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT   $realpath_root;
            internal;
                                            }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            return 404;
                           }
                   }

error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

With alias:

```
server {
server_name domain.tld www.domain.tld;
root /var/www/project/public;

    location /api {
        index index.php;
        alias /var/www/project/api/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /api/api/index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ ^/api/index\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME     index.php;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI    index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT   $realpath_root;
            internal;
                                          }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            return 404;
                           }
                   }


error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

For understand how it must be i am used

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

and

```
#tcpdump -nAs 20000 -i lo tcp port 9000
```